How do you make a K-Map when you're missing a few variables?
I've got the following problem -

That's got the following solution:

And I don't understand how this K-Map was made. Every exercise I've encountered thus far always has equations that have 3 elements(?) in each term(?)  and I don't know how to handle ones that have fewer.
What's worse is that I emailed my instructor and he's sent back this equally inscrutable bit of help:

Could someone please explain what's happening here so I can replicate it later?

So does that mean term 3 = 110 and I should be putting a 1 in the "110" spot on the resulting K-Map? Likewise term 4 = 011, etc?
Another thing I just noticed is that there are 6 1's in the K-Map but only 5 terms, is this a typo or have I missed something crucial here?

Take term 3.
$$B \overline C = B \overline C \times 1 = B \overline C (\overline A + A) = \overline AB \overline C + AB \overline C$$
Your instructor is showing you what you understand.  A two variable term equates to two three variable terms.
What they are hoping you to get is two variable terms equates to 2 adjacent terms.  Term 3 equates to X10 (010 AND 110), where a 1 must be placed in 2 adjacent squares of k-map, where B=1 AND C=0 and X is a don't care.
A one variable term equates to 4 adjacent squares in a square or row.
Your answer has three terms.  A one variable term and two 2-variable terms.


"A two variable term equatesto two three variable terms" <- That did it, thank you so much. I don't think I could have figured this out unless someone pointed it out.
